# IE8 jquery - browser content totaly grey

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Good morning!

We are facing a problem using IE8 with jquery dialog windows. As soon as we click on a button which cases jquery dialog window to be shown, the whole screen immediately gets grey and we cannot click any button on it.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean the browser locks, or just that you see a modal overlay but no modal?

Comment: @Tim Medora Browser does not lock - just the whole window gets gray and I can see that dialog window but it has been grayed as well - I cannot click anywhere

Comment: Well, that sounds more like the browser *has* locked. Does it respond to anything?

Comment: @Tim Medora some textboxes work - I can enter text but am unable to click buttons and press Enter

Comment: I'd suggest creating a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) sample which reproduces the problem so that people can look at it. If you can't create a working sample, I'd suggest backing things out of your real page until the problem goes away. Or commenting everything out and adding things back in until you see the issue.

Comment: Possibly a z-index issue? maybe the layer that is used to mask off the rest of the site (`<div class="ui-widget-overlay" >...</div>`) is somehow higher than the dialog